# Implement equals and hashcode for singleton?

Tags: java, singleton, equals, hashcode

I think it is a good way to always implement custom `equals(...)` and `hashCode()` for every class. But would is it useful to implement those methods for a singleton?

Should you implement them and just return the `==` case in equals method and any random int for the hash or just not implement them and use the implicit methods? What is the best practice?

Comment: You don't need to implement them in a singleton.

Comment: So you think it is the best practice to use the implicit object class methods?

Comment: Since, by definition, there is only at most one instance of a singleton class, what does equals and hashcode matter?

Comment: The default implementations give reference equality, which is correct for a singleton.

Comment: I think it depends how you use that singleton class, and it is mutable or immutable, and when it mutated also it's hash value is needed to be re-calculated.  I am just thinking...

Comment: If there is truly only 1 allowed instance then identity IS equality.